# PHP not posting data via curl

Tags: php, post, curl

I have a form that you can select a date range (#StartDate - #EndDate or #AllDates) and it writes the data to a .csv file and forces download. for whatever reason, I cannot pass the #StartDate and #EndDate values. they are generated by glDatePicker field, but even when I put in hardcoded values they aren't being passed. I run a $('#StartDate').val(); in console and it returns the date, however when I uncomment the

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

it returns an empty array. The back end script is using:

```
`FuncitionNameHere(trim($_POST["AllDates"]), trim($_POST["StartDate"]), trim($_POST["EndDate"]))`
```

the relevant part is

```
<form action="path/to/curl.php" method="post" id="Form6">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <label for="StartDate">Start Date</label>
            <input type="text" id="StartDate" name="StartDate" />
        </li>
        <li>    
            <label for="EndDate">End Date</label>
            <input type="text" id="EndDate" name="EndDate" />
            <input type="submit" id="Button6" value="Send" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="AllDates"><input type="checkbox" name="AllDates" id="AllDates" value="YES"> All Dates</label>
        </li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

and the curl script that sends data to remote db

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $url = 'https://remoteurl.com';
    $StartDate = $_POST["StartDate"];
    $EndDate = $_POST["EndDate"];
    $AllDates = $_POST["AllDates"];
    $fields = array(
        'StartDate'=>urldecode($StartDate),
        'EndDate'=>urldecode($EndDate),
        'AllDates'=>urldecode($AllDates)
    );
    foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
    $fields_string = rtrim($fields_string,'& ');
    //var_dump($_POST);
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    session_write_close();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $directory='/home/XXX/public_html/XXX/';
    $filename = 'Report.csv';
    $handle = fopen($directory.$filename, 'w');
    fwrite($handle, $output);
    header('Content-type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Report.csv"');
    echo $output;
?>
```

Any obvious reason why #AllDates is being posted but no value for #StartDate or #EndDate is being posted?

Comment: How are you submitting the form?

Comment: Sorry not sure what you mean? its an submitHandler: function(form) {
   $('#prcs6').fadeIn('fast').delay(2000).fadeOut('fast');
   $('#StartDate, #EndDate').delay(2000).val("");
         form.submit();
         return false;
     },

Comment: Via JS, that's what I was asking. By the way, did you check on your browser the HTTP request sent to curl.php? Check if those parameters are sent or not

Comment: they aren't getting sent, which is my issue. no idea why.

Comment: Did you try the 'dumb' test? :P
Try deleting everything from curl.php and just dump `$_POST`, see what happens

Comment: Yes, I try that and this is the var dump array(3) { ["StartDate"]=> string(0) "" ["EndDate"]=> string(0) "" ["FXCMAction"]=> string(6) "report" } they just aren't being passed for some reason

Comment: Wait, you said they were not sent, but that's not true. They are sent but they're empty. And that's because of this code:`$('#StartDate, #EndDate').delay(2000).val(""); ` You empty those input and then submit the form.

Comment: Thank you very much. I apologize for making such a dumb mistake, and appreciate you working through it with me. If you're into check marks/answers, please repost as an answer and I will gladly accept.

Comment: No problem, I'm here just to learn stuff, so no need to post/accept an answer. Glad I could help :)

Comment: Wow, thats how I feel. But get absolutely crucified here when I don't mark answer as accepted

Comment: @DirtyBirdDesign Please consider posting an answer yourself, and then accept it as a solution so the question will be marked as solved.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to parse out your `$_POST` like that. Just do this instead and it might fix your issue:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query( $_POST ));
```

Comment: I replaced this line curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string); with the above. No joy.

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer the question myself - although the credit goes to @Uby. Chrome was not posting data due to this:

`$('#StartDate, #EndDate').delay(2000).val("");`

Although it worked in other browsers. So my solution to clear the field values after submission was to do this

```
setTimeout(function(){ // Delay for Chrome
    $('#StartDate, #EndDate').val(''); // blank the input
}, 100);
```

Now it clears the field a split second after you hit submit, giving Chrome a chance to serialize the data before the fields are cleared.